# How to force a string inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div that contains some elements inside it(other divs that contain Strings), this div obeys class `item_block` and it contained in a big div called `gallery`, so, when i append this div to the gallery div with appending another elements besides a String, these elements fit in the div but that string don't, look at the following pic(the item_block is the **yellow** colored and the String is the brown colored):

[image]

```
 #gallery {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 35px;
}

      .item_block {
        background-origin:content-box;
        background-color:#DAD1A2;
        background-image:url(../Images/logo2.png);
        background-position:center;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height: 25%;
        width: 25%;
        line-height: 450px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-indent: 0px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: 5px;

    }
 .item_name {
    background-color: #68782C;
    position: absolute;
    height: 35%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    top: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**and I append the data inside JS with JQuery like that:**

```
$("#gallery").append('<div class="item_block hasoptions">price:'+$('menu').find(selecteditem).children().eq(si).attr('price') +'<div class="add_btn"></div><div class="item_name">'+ realitemname +'</div></div>');
```

And this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6tDb) of the whole code.

Comment: What's your relevant (**minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)**) HTML for this?

Comment: Can you send the full HTML code? or upload it to http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: the jsfiddle of the whole code added to the question